# What is the song when the female titan showed up at Levi's group in episode 18?

Tags: music, attack-on-titan

I started watching *Attack on Titan* and this song started playing in slow motion when the "Female Titan" showed up at Levi's group, around 20:30 of episode 18.

What song is this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did some digging, and this is what I found out. Shazam identified the song as: 
進撃st-Hrn-Gt-Pf20130629巨人

by 澤野弘之.You can also find it under the title" Rittai Kidou Remix".
Plz listen and correct me if I am wrong because I have also found other tracks as well. But this one was the most accurate, according to my listening experience.